# Word = smallWord1 + smallWord2

Tags: kotlin

> Look for all six letter words which are composed of two concatenated smaller words.

Please give me feedback regarding good coding standards.

```
import java.io.File
class KataExercise(val wordLength: Int) {
    fun concatenatedWords(): List<String> {
        val searchWords = dictionary
                .filter { it.length == wordLength }
        val result = mutableListOf<String>()
        for (subWord in smallDictionary) {
            val subWordLength = subWord.length
            (smallDictionary)
                    .filter { it.length + subWordLength == wordLength }
                    .map { it + subWord }
                    .filter { it in searchWords }
                    .forEach { result.add(it) }
        }
        return result.toList()
    }
    private val dictionary = File("dict.text").readLines()
            .filter { "'" !in it }
    private val smallDictionary: List<String> = dictionary
            .filter { it.length < wordLength}
}
```

Comment: where is "it" coming from?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon `it` is a language defined default name for a single parameter to an anonymous function. So `$0` in Swift.

Comment: @CarlFujinami - I'd like to see this code to be a little more readable. When you see code that's readable, it's sort of like reading a book or a sentence. it's easy to read and doesn't strain your eyes. you can just "get it" without thinking too much. i'd like to see the above to be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reduced mutation

```
val result = mutableListOf<String>()
for (subWord in smallDictionary) {
    val subWordLength = subWord.length
    (smallDictionary)
        .filter { it.length + subWordLength == wordLength }
        .map { it + subWord }
        .filter { it in searchWords }
        .forEach { result.add(it) }
}
return result.toList()
```

could be replaced with:

```
return smallDictionary
    .flatMap { first -> smallDictionary.map { first to it } }
    .filter { it.first.length + it.second.length == wordLength }
    .map { it.first + it.second }
    .filter { it in searchWords }
```

## Optimisation

You could filter the 2 lists so the starting list is only words that start with the same letter as the target word, and the ending list is only words that end with the last letter of the target word, for a large wordlist this in theory could reduce the size of these lists by a large amount.

Comment: Do I just need to .flatten your code? I'm asking because my new code has a bug in it which returns an empty array for concat().

Comment: I don't think so, the return should be a list of 2 part words (although they may be duplicated)

Answer (score 0):

It looks quite good.

I was miffed for a few seconds on `(smallDictionary)` alone on a line.  I think it's better without the parentheses.

Another small detail is that I would have defined `dictionary` and `smallDictionary` before the function.

#### Algorithm

On the algorithm side, I think this could be improved.  You basically have two `for`-loops over the whole dictionary: `.filter { it in searchWords }` is also a `for`-loop.  If you made `searchWords` a *set* instead of a list, it would be much faster.

You scan the complete dictionary twice: to build `smallDictionary` and to build `searchWords`.  You could instead use one filter for everything smaller or equal to 6 letters followed by a [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) by length.  You would have have the set for 6 letter words, and you could build the set of the smaller words.  But you could make your algorithm more efficient by not grouping those and instead just looking in the one set of the right size when you are looking for the complementary word.

#### Algorithm Ideas

- Another idea would be to carry your main loop over the 6 letter words, and then use a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (aka radix tree) to quickly find the shorter words which might make up the start of the 6 letter word.  But I have not thought this through and it might be slower.  You can look into it if you want.
- Another idea would be to subtract the letters of a small word to the letters of a six letter word and then check if that unordered combination of letters  (including the number of occurrence of each letter) is in some hash map.  The key of the map is this bag of letters (with occurrence count) and the value(s) are the possible words with those letters.  Again, I have not thought this through.

Answer (score 0):

So I've implemented the suggestions by toto2 and jrtapsell, and optimized it by using Maps for the first letter of searcWords.

```
import java.io.File

class KataExercise(val wordLength: Int) {
    fun concatenatedWords(): List<String> {
                return wordPairList()
                        .filter { it.first.length + it.second.length == wordLength }
                        .map { it.first + it.second }
                        .filter { it in smallSearchWords(it.first()) }
    }

    private fun wordPairList(): List<Pair<String, String>> {
        val tinyDictionary = smallDictionary.filter { it.length < wordLength - 1}
        return tinyDictionary
                .flatMap { first ->
                    tinyDictionary
                            .map { first to it }
                }
    }
    private val smallDictionary =
            File("dict.text").readLines()
                    .filter { "'" !in it }
                    .filter { 1 < it.length && it.length <= wordLength}


    private val searchWords = 
            smallDictionary
                    .filter { it.length == wordLength }

    private val groupedSearchWords =
            searchWords
                    .groupBy { it.first() }

    private fun smallSearchWords(char: Char): List<String> {
        return groupedSearchWords
                .filter { it.key == char }
                .map { it.value }
                .flatten()
    }

}
```